# SQL - Command to find rows from two columns of different tables with same D.O.B

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to select those faculty rows which have the same month of birth as that of students, but this code doesn't seem to work. "SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier" is the error being displayed.

```
SELECT STUDENT.FIRSTNAME, STUDENT.DOB, FACULTY.FIRSTNAME, FACULTY.DOB
FROM STUDENT, FACULTY
HAVING MONTH(STUDENT.DOB) = MONTH(FACULTY.DOB);
```

Comment: Try changing `having` to `where` (or moving it to an actual `join` -- generally I recommend avoiding commas in your `from` clause)...  If that doesn't work, post sample data and expected results.

Comment: What sgeddes said, and also the syntax is `extract(month from student.dob)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this:

```
SELECT STUDENT.FIRSTNAME, STUDENT.DOB, FACULTY.FIRSTNAME, FACULTY.DOB
FROM STUDENT, FACULTY 
where
extract(month from STUDENT.DOB)=extract(month from FACULTY.DOB)
```